# how to set smtp to notify if message hadn't delivered

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail, smtplib

I am trying to send message via smtp with python smtplib but not showing error when it hadn't delivered

I am trying to use `gmail smtp` (python) using this command

```
rcpt_options = ['NOTIFY=SUCCESS,DELAY,FAILURE']
  smtp.sendmail(user+'@'+host,email,msg.as_string(), rcpt_options=rcpt_options)
  response =smtp.noop()[1]
  print(response)
```

The response is

```
(250, b'2.0.0 OK u22-20020a170906125600b00965b416585bsm1930427eja.118 - gsmtp')
```

but actually the message wasn't sent because the email bounced. I want to know how to check the delivery status of the message using smtp.